# Another Azure ML bug caused by new Compute Common Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Many of my Azure ML Studio Designer pipelines began failing today.  I was able to make a minimum repro:

[image]

Simply excluding columns with the `Select Columns In Dataset` node will fail with a `JobConfigurationMaxSizeExceeded` error.

This appears to be a bug introduced by Microsoft's rollout of their new Compute Common Runtime.

If I go into any nodes failing with the `JobConfigurationMaxSizeExceeded` exception and manually set `AZUREML_COMPUTE_USE_COMMON_RUNTIME:false` in their  `Environment JSON` field, then they will subsequently work correctly.  This is not documented anywhere that I could find, I stumbled over this fix through trial-and-error, and I wasted many hours trying to fix our failing pipelines today.

Does anyone know where I can find a list of possible effects of the Compute Common Runtime migration in Azure ML? I could not find any documentation on this and/or how it might affect existing Azure ML pipelines.

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate, but without an answer I can't mark it as such) question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279636/azure-auto-ml-jobconfigurationmaxsizeexceeded-error-when-using-a-cluster

Comment: Here is a related question with an answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252478/azure-machine-learning-designer-error-jobconfigurationmaxsizeexceeded

However, the possible duplicate you posted is not quite a duplicate in my opinion.  It involves the Automated ML tool, which is separate from the Designer.  I just looked and I also can not find where to set environment vars for Automated ML runs.

Answer (score 0):

runtime environment variable should be set on the run configuration. property on the Environment object is deprecated.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.runconfig.runconfiguration?view=azure-ml-py#variables

Comment: @Yunnosch you might be not familiar with AzureML hence you do not see the connection, though as an area owner I asure you it is related. User incorrectly sets runtime variable in environment object and I pointed to the right location. Please start with this page if you want to become familiar with AzureML https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning

Comment: Add that explanation to the answer itself and it even is obvious to me. ;-)